# i2c Permament ownership setting

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w, permissions

I set up an apache2 server on my RPi zero and written cgi script that reads temperature from database and prints it onto a website. To update data in the database, I have a small python script which collects data from BMP180 sensor and writes it to the database (does it every 10 min by cron job).

Now, here comes the trouble: the script needs to have permission to read from */dev/i2c-1*. I changed the ownership of this folder to www-data but the ownership is cancelled after each reboot. Is there a way to set the ownership permanently or execute this task in any other way? Doing chmod after every reboot seems like a very bad solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Raspbian members of group `i2c` have access to the I2C devices.

If you are using Raspbian you could make `www-data` a member of the `i2c` group.

`sudo adduser www-data i2c`